# Dealing with file objects in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have asked a question based on this before but no solutions have worked for me and now I'm completely lost.

I want to be able to upload an image and have it save to the assets folder of my Angular 2 project.

At the moment I have the file object but I can't figure out what to do with it next or how I should go about saving it.

Here is my input field for the file

```
<input type="file" name="image" (change)="saveImageToFile($event)" accept="image/*" required>
```

Here is the function that deals with that file:

```
saveImageToFile(e) {
   this.image = e.srcElement.files[0];
   console.log(this.image);
}
```

This logs the image object but I don't know how to go about saving it. I have tried setting up a form data object but when I try to append the file to it, it is still empty. I have a Java/Spring-boot back-end but I can't even get it to send to the back-end.

Comment: No clear what the problem is. This is pretty straightforward. Create FormData object, append('image', this.image). Send formData object with AJAX.]

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for the reply. I have tried that, its when I append to FormData object and send it, the FormData object gets sent through as being empty.

Comment: How do you know it's empty? you can easily check if client (browser) sends file or not (Network tab, explore request headers). then you just need to set up server properly to accept and handle it.